# How do I request azure spot instances using terraform, in a virtual machine scale set?

Tags: linux, azure, terraform

Apologies in advance if I'm posing the question poorly, but I'd appreciate some help requesting spot instances in the context of a linux vmss.

Here is the reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.html#identity

and the relevant piece of it:

[image]

And here is their example json, without any indication of where the optional arguments go:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1
  admin_username      = "adminuser"

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    }
  }
}
```

I want to put the following two lines somewhere:

```
priority            = var.spot_priority
eviction_policy     = var.spot_eviction_policy
```

but when I put them at the top level, I get this error:

```
Error: expected priority to be one of [Low Regular], got Spot
```

(obviously I've got it set to "Spot" in the `terraform.tfvars`

I've tried inserting them in various blocks, but they give me unexpected argument errors.

Where do I tell terraform that I want spot instances??

EDIT:  The problem is solved by passing in "Low" rather than "Spot" in the top level of the vmss resource.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? It's free to get more help for this issue.

Comment: @CharlesXu sorry to not reply.  I upvoted your answer, but it turns out that with my version of terraform, "low" was the same thing as "spot".  Specifying "low" rather than "spot" worked fine.  I was being a bit dense.

Comment: I recommend you use the newest version. It has more features and fixes something inconvenient. And this version is more appropriate currently.

Answer (score 4):

I also use the example that `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set` provide and add the `priority` and `eviction_policy` like this:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1
  admin_username      = "adminuser"

  priority = "Spot"
  eviction_policy = "Deallocate"

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    }
  }
}
```

And it works fine. When I try to plan it, it shows:

[image]

I use the Terraform version 0.12.19 and the azurerm version 2.20. So you can use the same version as mine and try again.